# ffmpeg creates large compressed files for tiny videos?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, h.264, h.265

When compressing very small videos, there seems to be a large overhead in the video container itself.

Here are some examples using a single-frame 16x16-pixel all-black image:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=16x16:r=1:duration=1 -y /tmp/v1.mp4
wc -c /tmp/v1.mp4
# 1625 bytes

ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=16x16:r=1:duration=1 -codec:v hevc -y /tmp/v2.mp4
wc -c /tmp/v2.mp4
# 3165 bytes


ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=16x16:r=1:duration=1 -y /tmp/v1.h264
wc -c /tmp/v1.h264
# 744 bytes

ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=16x16:r=1:duration=1 -codec:v hevc -y /tmp/v2.hevc
wc -c /tmp/v2.hevc
# 2354 bytes
```

All these numbers look unexpectedly large.  Is `ffmpeg` storing some unwanted metadata?

Is there any way to avoid these big overheads, especially for `HEVC`?

By comparison, image codecs look much more compact:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=16x16:r=1:duration=1 -y /tmp/v1.png
wc -c /tmp/v1.png
# 94 bytes

ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=16x16:r=1:duration=1 -y /tmp/v1.jpg
wc -c /tmp/v1.jpg
# 222 bytes
```

Comment: Are you referring to the difference between the raw bitstream (.h264) and in containers (.mp4)?

Comment: The discussion in the question shows that both the bitstream and container have significant overhead, particularly for HEVC -- about 2300 and 3100 total bytes respectively.  I'd be interested in reducing either one.

Comment: The idea is that a uniform-color 16x16 image should compress to very few bytes.

Comment: The size of the bitstream is determined by the encoder (x264 and x265, in this case, not ffmpeg). The overhead for the container is due to the required header structure. For this toy example or the like, you're better off just emitting an uncompressed stream and then using a general purpose compressor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to remove the stored "SEI user encoder settings":

- For x264: https://forum.selur.net/showthread.php?tid=1282
- For x265: --[no-]info  Emit SEI identifying encoder and parameters. Default enabled

Using the above example:

```
ffmpeg -i /tmp/v1.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v 'filter_units=remove_types=6' -y /tmp/v3.mp4
wc -c /tmp/v3.mp4
# 837 bytes (down from 1625 bytes)

ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=16x16:r=1:duration=1 -codec:v hevc -x265-params info=0 -y /tmp/v4.mp4
wc -c /tmp/v4.mp4
# 903 bytes (down from 3165 bytes)

ffmpeg -i /tmp/v1.h264 -c copy -bsf:v 'filter_units=remove_types=6' -y /tmp/v3.h264
wc -c /tmp/v3.h264
# 56 bytes (down from 744 bytes)

ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=16x16:r=1:duration=1 -codec:v hevc -x265-params info=0 -y /tmp/v3.hevc
wc -c /tmp/v3.hevc
# 97 bytes (down from 2354 bytes)
```

Comment: For the case of the MP4 container, perhaps there is still unnecessary data there?